# La fonction $f$ admet-elle une fonction réciproque?

Tags: functions

Bonsoir j'ai un petit problème avec un exercice.

On considère la function $f:[-1,1] \to [-\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2}]$ définie par $f(x) = \frac{x}{1+x²}$.

Je dois montrer que f admet une fonction réciproque et définir cette fonction.
Merci pour votre aide.

"Hello, I have a little problem with an exercise. Consider the function $f\colon[−1,1]\to[−\tfrac12,\tfrac12]$ defined by $f(x)=\frac x{1+x^2}$. I have to show that $f$ admits an inverse function and define that function. Thanks for your help." (Translation by Hagen von Eitzen as in the comments.)

Comment: English, please

Comment: He is looking for an inverse function

Comment: "Hello, I have a little problem with an exercise. Consider the function $f\colon[-1,1]\to [-\tfrac12,\tfrac12]$ defined by $f(x)=\frac x{1+x^2}$. Show that $f$ admits an inverse function and define that function. Thanks for your help" (I guess, je suis desole that I don't speak a siungle word of French)

Comment: @Khalid. Nous ne parle pas Francais, parce que c'est beaucoup difficile.

Comment: Yes I have some baggage in english, But not well.
I'm looking for an inverse function that:
f:[-1,1] -> [-1/2,1/2]
x        -> x/(1+x²)

Comment: @imranfat "nous ne parlons pas". "parle" is the singular form.

Comment: @JanDvorak. You are absolutely right here. It has been too long. But watch out, Khalid knows much more English then he want us to know. I bet his English is better than my French

Comment: Ceci me fait plaisir.

Comment: @JanDvorak This is [not an English-only site](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/1617); adding a translation is fine and good, but please do not remove the original question text.

Answer (score 5):

La fonction étant dérivable et sa dérivée est
$$f'(x)=\frac{1-x^2}{(1+x^2)^2}>0,\;\forall x\in]-1,1[$$
donc $f$ est continue et strictement croissante sur son domaine de définition donc elle admet une fonction réciproque. Pour déterminer $f^{-1}$ on exprime $x$ en fonction de $y$ dans l'égalité:
$$y=f(x)$$
en résolvant une équation de second degré.

**Translation**

The function is differentiable and its derivative is 
$$ f '(x) = \frac {1-x ^ 2} {(1 + x ^ 2) ^ 2} >0, \, \forall x \in( -1,1 )$$ 
so $ f $ is continuous and strictly increasing on its domain of definition so it admits an inverse function. To determine $f ^ {-1}$ we express $ x $  in terms of $ y $ in the equation: 
$$ y = f (x) $$ 
by solving a quadratic equation.

Comment: En réalité, la fonction $f$ est strictement croissante. (Pourquoi voter +1 pour cette réponse ?) // Actually, the function $f$ is increasing. (Why the upvote?)

Comment: @Did J'ai édité  ma réponse. Merci. // I edited my answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Hint : Solve the following equation in $x$
 $y=\frac{x}{1+x^2}$
You will get 2 solutions. Because of the domain, only one makes sense

Comment: Can u give me the full correction, plz.
because when I tried to searched for a solution, I has a problem at that:
yx² + y - x = 0.
and thank u for you help.

Comment: Using the discriminant (what you got is an equation of degree 2), you get two solutions: $\frac{1+\sqrt{1-4y^2}}{2y}$ and $\frac{1-\sqrt{1-4y^2}}{2y}$.

Comment: Thank u so much, That's what I reached by.